# Rails saving nested Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am have the following models

```
users (id, name, ...)
authorizations (id, provider, provider_uid, token, user_id, ...)
```

> users has_many authorizations

```
@user = User.new(first_name: facebook_client.first_name,
                                 last_name: facebook_client.last_name,
                                 email: facebook_client.email,
                                 bio: facebook_client.bio,
                                 date_of_birth: facebook_client.birthday,
                                 gender: facebook_client.gender,
                                 location: facebook_client.location)

    @user.authorizations.build(
                    provider: 'facebook',
                    provider_uid: facebook_client.user_id,
                    oauth_token: facebook_user_token,
                    social_account: SocialAccount.friendly.find('facebook'))
```

i have a validation

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

Because of the above i am not able to save when i do `@user.save`

I am not able to understand why it should not save when i am building it via `@user.authorizations.build`

Comment: because `@user.id` is `nil`, it is not persisted.

Comment: @Зелёный but its not not saved. when i save [at]user it saves the user then it saves the nested models so it automatically saves the id right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

> If you want to be sure that an association is present, you'll need to test whether the associated object itself is present, and **not the foreign key used** to map the association.

This means you have to replace your `validates :user_id, presence: true` validation to the following:

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorizations, inverse_of: :user
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the given code is complete, this is simply because you have not saved (persisted) @user, so it has no id. It needs an id to create an association (which links to that record via its id).

If you check in your code, you should be seeing:

```
@user = User.new...
@user.id => nil
```

A record with no id cannot have any associations (that are not belongs_to).